# Geometry package: use of dynamic spacing variables in class definition

Tags: geometry

I am trying to replicate my company's corporate design Word template in LaTeX and got a manual with all relevant measures:

[image]

Unfortunately, most of them refer to the baseline height of the first line, while the `top` parameter of LaTeX' `geometry` package defines upper edge of the text area.

I got close to the desired result using

```
\newgeometry{
    top=60.5mm-\baselineskip
}
```

inside the document, but

1. The true height to subtract depends on the actual fontsize, so with
   `\scriptsize` in the footer or header, `\baselineskip` is not fully
   correct (?)
2. This works using `newgeometry` inside the document, but
   throws errors when using it in `\usepackage[top=60.5mm-\baselineskip]{geometry}` in a
   `.cls` style class

Is there a good way to use the actual height of a 10pt and 7pt font for the geometric position calculation, ideally right in the style class?

Comment: The first baseline on the page is `\topskip` below the top margin (unless the line height exceeds it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `\dimexpr...\relax` to do calculations on the fly in a place like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=\dimexpr 60.5mm-\baselineskip\relax]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

However, since you say the given dimensions "refer to the baseline height of the first line", what you really want (hat tip John K.) is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=\dimexpr 60.5mm-\topskip\relax]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

since `\topskip` is the height of only the text-space allocation *above the baseline* (note, my original suggestion was `\ht\strutbox`, which also includes the dead-zone above the lettered area).

Something to note:  since the specification is to the baseline, there is no need to tweak the `\topskip` to match, for example, a first line specified in  `\scriptsize`.   That is to say, if you were to change the first line, instead, to `\tiny\lipsum[1]`, you will find the distance to the baseline of the first line of text **does not change**!  This observation will be true as long as the revised `\ht\strutbox` remains smaller than the original baselineskip (generally up to `\large` or `\Large`).  Once that is exceeded, the 1st line of the page will be pushed downward.

See it here graphically, with a red bar extending exactly 60.5mm down the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=\dimexpr 60.5mm-\topskip\relax]{geometry}\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{\textcolor{red}{#3}}}}}
\atxy{1.5in}{0in}{\rule[-60.5mm]{2pt}{60.5mm}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\the\ht\strutbox \the\topskip \the\baselineskip
\clearpage
\tiny\lipsum[1]

\the\ht\strutbox \the\topskip \the\baselineskip

\clearpage
\huge\lipsum[1]

\the\ht\strutbox \the\topskip \the\baselineskip
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

---

`\normalsize`:

[image]

---

`\tiny`:

[image]

---

`\huge`:

[image]

Comment: Why not use \topskip, or isn't it available before geometry runs?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I learn something new every day, apparently.